# Rails generate URL with values from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, url

I am new to rails/ruby and I need your help. I want to generate an URL with the values of the form.

For example:

In the form you can select different options: a, b and c. I want to put the selected options to the url.

www.mydomain.com/a,b,c

Thats all. But I don´t know where to start.

Do you have any idea? Of course I worked trough different tutorials, but in this tutorial every form is saving it values to a database and that is fine, but i couldn't find a solution for my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a [`GET` request](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp), as this sends the params in the URL like this:

```
domain.com/route?param1=x&param2=y
```

This will need to be backed up by `GET` routes to handle the request:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :controller do
    collection do
        get :action
    end
end
```

and a form which submits via `GET`:

```
<%= form_for @var, method: :get do |f| %>
```

---

Of course, this is just the surface-level solution

If you provide some context, I'll be able to give you a much better answer